# extract a concrete part of a value from a Response to a new string Groovy script

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I'm kinda new in groovy and I need help

I need to write a groovy script to transform or else extract a concrete value from a Json Response to a new string Groovy script.

and the groovy script I used is this one :

```
 responseJson = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Test Scenario").getPropertyValue("response")
 parsedResponse = slurper.parseText(responseJson) 
log.info(parsedResponse["items"]["/ticket_id"])
```

My generated string response from the groovy script I use looks like this:

```
/ticket_id":"{\"isTodo\":false,\"items\":[[\"WhatIwantToExtract\",\"\",\"url.com:blablabla_qc_vpc-11:Machine:data-da-data\",timestamp]]}
```

The response is correct in fact but I just want to extract a piece of this

The data I wanted to extract is labeled above as " WhatIwantToExtract " without the commas.

Comment: Use JsonSlurper to parse text, and then just access required item.

Comment: Any example on how do I access it

Comment: Check the groovy documentation about json and JsonSlurper: http://groovy-lang.org/json.html http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it

```
def regexResult = (parsedResponse["items"][0][0])
```